How to automatically create OnClick event handler for custom Delphi component on double-click in IDE?
I'm creating a custom Delphi component (like a TButton) and want the IDE to generate an OnClick event handler when the component is double-clicked in the Form Designer. However, I'm unsure how to implement this functionality programmatically.
How can I configure my custom component so that double-clicking it in the Delphi IDE automatically create an OnClick skeleton event handler?

You need to set a components default event handler. You can read more about this on How to set a component's default event handler. Unfortunately I can't find suitable information in Delphi's own documentation to link that instead.

And based on that article, OnClick is one of the events that the IDE looks for by default, so if the event is present in the component then the IDE will generate a handler for it without you having to write any code for it. Unless one of the other default events is also present in the component that has higher priority than OnClick, then you do need a write a custom component editor.
